# Não permitir que o onBackPressed seja executado

Tags: android

Na minha aplicação, quando o usuário faz login se ele apertar o `onBackPressed()` do smartphone dele a aplicação não deveria voltar para tela anterior. 
Quando ele faz login e eu troco de activity eu setei na Intent o seguinte código:

```
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Em alguns celulares o seguinte código funciona.. Em outros não. O que fazer?

Answer (score 3):

Para evitar que o `onBackPressed()` faça alguma coisa em alguma `Activity` basta sobrescrevê-lo na `Activity` em questão:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Não faz nada
}
```

Porém no seu caso creio que o ideal seria finalizar a `Activity` de login chamando `finish()` logo em seguida ao `startActivity()` que inicia a segunda activity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, SegundaActivity.class));
finish();
```

Assim a activity de login sai da pilha de activities e fica a segunda activity no topo.