# Após o login, impedir que o aplicativo volte à tela de login com o botão de voltar

Tags: android

No meu sistema de login, eu digito os dados e faço ele abrir uma activity nova se os dados estiverem certos.

Até ai tudo bem. Mas quando clico em voltar (a ideia seria fechar o aplicativo), ele simplesmente mostra a tela de login. Como destruir a tela de login, no momento que eu logar e abrir uma nova tela?

Comment: Dê uma olhada também [nessa outra](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93764/n%c3%a3o-permitir-que-o-onbackpressed-seja-executado) pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode colocar finish(); após o intent para que ele feche a activity atual ao passar para nova.

Espero ter ajudado.